# How can I include a generated code project in a Visual Studio SLN?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-generation

I have a project with a single Visual Studio SLN that's made up of a number of CSPROJ files. One of those projects is an EXE (compiled from C#) that reads in a text file and churns out a .CS file based on that text file.

Decades ago, I'd have written a Makefile. Is there a way I can trigger this kind of auto generated code in Visual Studio 2022 when I press F5?

- If I modify the text file, I'd like the EXE that generates `autogen.cs` to be called.
- When `autogen.cs` changes, I'd like `autogen.dll` (the DLL it compiles into) to be rebuilt.
- When `autogen.dll` updates, I'd like any project referencing that DLL to be rebuilt.

(All of these projects are yet to be written, so I'm happy to rethink the way they work.)

Comment: As far as I can see you can just create the project that contains your autogen.cs and make a T4 template that builds autogen.cs.

Comment: There are code generation features in VS22 integrated in the MSBuild, [ms documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/tutorial-custom-task-code-generation?view=vs-2022) could help you.

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/tutorial-custom-task-code-generation?view=vs-2022). Microsoft official documentation introduces automatic code generation.